# javascript: using closure to 'freeze' the value of i in a for loop

Tags: javascript, closures

This question is taken from the first question in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684917/what-questions-should-a-javascript-programmer-be-able-to-answer

```
<a href="#">text</a><br><a href="#">link</a>
 <script>
 var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(i);
        return false;
    }
 }
</script>
```

Why do the anchors, when clicked on, alert -1 instead of their respective counter inside of the loop? How can you fix the code so that it does alert the right number? (Hint: closures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `onclick` fires the value of `i` is `-1` (because that's the last value `i` will get).

The solution is to make a closure that binds that value of `i` *in that step of the iteration* to the onclick-listener.

One possible way to fix it is:

```
for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {
    as[i].onclick = (function(actually_i) {
        return function () {
            alert(actually_i);
            return false;
        }
    }(i)) // pass in i
}
```

---

There are other things wrong with this code. Here is how I would write it:

```
for (var i; i < as.length; i += 1) {
    as[i].addEventListener("click", (function(actually_i) {
        return function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(actually_i);
        }
    }(i)) // pass in i
}
```

- `i--` construction is too clever and leads to bugs
- better to use `addEventListener` instead of assigning `onclick` (modularity issues).
- preventDefault is intended, not stopPropagation. `return false` does both and is always wrong.

Comment: In summary, you use a closure to return the function that handles the click event. That function receives the current value of i inside the closure as input parameter. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeToad According to this definition : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures, the closure is the returned function, and it is so called only because it refers to an outer variable, as it happens, `actually_i`.

Answer (score 2):

Current scenario :

1. Loop 1 (`i = 1`) : sets click on first link.
2. Loop 2 (`i = 0`) : sets click on second link.
3. After the second loop, `i` equals `-1`.
4. Click occurs : `i` still equals `-1`.

Using an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) allows to create an entirely new context in which the value of `i` has nothing to do with `i` anymore. Then, considering the example below, the term "[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)" refers to the relationship between `j` and the returned function which will serve as a click handler :

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {
    as[i].onclick = function (j) {
        return function () {
            alert(i + ' ' + j);
            return false;
        };
    }(i);
}
```